# Organization of SQL code in a PHP library

Tags: php, mysql, code-organization

Is it better to put all the SQL code into one library than scatter it about your web site?

I.e. effeciency in not loading library compared to knowing where and what the SQL code is?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL code" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about initializing everything, yes.  Look for any of the Database.php classes and use them, it makes SQL as easy as $db->query($sql) and will return an associative array.  Some even let you use $db->query($sql, $key) and will return an associative array based on what key you provide, where the key is a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics it's hard to say for certain.

In a small project it maybe a bit more efficient to deal with each query as it's required rather than loading an include, but in general I would say yes it is worth doing.

Your question doesn't specify whether you are planing on loading a file of functions or a database class. In general you want to avoid repeating your code ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) so if you are doing the same or very similar queries or even different queries but with the same configuration include a class or functions file.